# Update many_to_many association in nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, simple-form, wicked-gem

I have three models for the context of this question. And using the `wicked` gem for multi-step signup.

#### User

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :profile
  has_many :specialties, through: :profile

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, allow_destroy: true
end
```

#### Profile

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :profile_specialties
  has_many :specialties, through: :profile_specialties
end
```

#### Specialty

```
class Specialty < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :profile_specialties
  has_many :profiles, through: :profile_specialties
end
```

In my form, I pass `specialty_ids`

```
<%= simple_form_for @user, url: wizard_path do |f| %>

  ...

  <%= simple_fields_for :profile_attributes do |cf| %>

    <%= cf.input :specialty_ids, collection: Role.order(:name), as: :grouped_select, group_method: :specialties, input_html: {multiple: true} %>

  <% end %>

  ...

<% end %>
```

to the `AfterSignup#update`

```
def update
  @user = current_user
  @user.update_attributes(user_params)
  render_wizard @user
end
```

I believed that rails handled the update of associations through naming. But maybe I'm mistaken and need to explicitly update the associations in the controller. Or perhaps I've not named items correctly...

Either way, I'm a little unclear on why the profile specialties don't update.

### Update

When I try to do a update, the console logs `Unpermitted parameters: :specialty_ids`

I have strong params defined as such

```
def user_params
  params.permit profile_attributes: [..., :specialty_ids]
end
```

### Update 2

Here is the full log

```
Processing by AfterSignupController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "profile_attributes"=>{"specialty_ids"=>["", "22"], "commit"=>"Save and Continue", "id"=>"step_one"}
  User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 52], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameters: :specialty_ids
Unpermitted parameters: :utf8, :_method, :authenticity_token, :commit, :id
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  Profile Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 52], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" = $1  [["id", 110]]
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "profiles" ("user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["user_id", 52], ["created_at", "2018-09-06 02:30:57.882173"], ["updated_at", "2018-09-06 02:30:57.882173"]]
   (0.5ms)  COMMIT
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/after_signup/requirements
```

Comment: What is the entire console message, there is important info in there. What do the params you are trying to pass LOOK like in the console? Is params expecting an array of IDs?

Comment: @Beartech I've added the full message

Comment: `params[:speciality_ids]` is an array. Try `params.permit profile_attributes: [..., specialty_ids: []]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strong params is expecting an array so you need:

```
def user_params
  params.permit profile_attributes: [..., specialty_ids: []]
end
```

Comment: ah, there it was. much more simple than I expected.

Comment: Params can be a pain sometimes.